# cancel button using MBProgressView

Tags: swift, selector, mbprogresshud

I am trying to use cancel button with the MBProgressView. I am getting the error "cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'Selector'"

```
hud.button.addTarget(hud.progressObject, action: cancelButton(), for: .touchUpInside)
```

I have also tried doing this:

```
hud.button.addTarget(hud.progressObject, action: #selector(cancelButton), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and I got the error "Argument of #selector cannot refer to local function 'cancelButton()'".

Can anyone explain to me what am i doing wrong?

cancelButton should be in viewDidLoad or at least I need to find a way to access what's inside viewDidload, because I need to use hud and snapshot.progress to cancel the download:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appdelegate.orintation = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
        if book?.bookPath !=  book?.bookPath {
            print("HERE \(book?.bookPath)")
            loadReader(filePaht: (book?.bookPath)!)
        } else {
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
            let strName = book?.id
            let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/"+strName!+".pdf"
            let fileManager = FileManager.default

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
                loadReader(filePaht: filePath)
                return;
            }

            print("DOWNLOAD #1")

            let reference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: (self.book?.bookURL)!)
            let downloadTask =  reference.data(withMaxSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {

                } else {

                    if ((try! data?.write(to: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath, isDirectory: false))) != nil) {
                        self.db.upDate(id: (self.book?.id)!, bookPath: filePath)
                        self.loadReader(filePaht: filePath)
                    }
                }
            }
            downloadTask.observe(.resume) { (snapshot) -> Void in
                // Download resumed, also fires when the download starts
            }
            downloadTask.observe(.pause) { (snapshot) -> Void in
                // Download paused
            }


                downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) -> Void in

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {() -> Void in
                self.showHUDWithCancel("Downloading")
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                })
            })

            self.hud.progressObject = snapshot.progress

        }
            downloadTask.observe(.success) { (snapshot) -> Void in
                // Download completed successfully

                print("Download Success")

                SwiftLoader.hide()
            }

            downloadTask.observe(.failure) { (snapshot) -> Void in
                //Download failed

                print("Download failed")
            }


        }


    }
    func showHUDWithCancel(_ aMessage: String) {
        self.hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        self.hud.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.annularDeterminate
        self.hud.label.text = aMessage
        self.hud.detailsLabel.text = "Tap to cancel"
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cancelButton))
        self.hud.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func cancelButton() {

       self.hud.hide(animated: true)
        self.hud.progressObject?.cancel()

        print("cancel button is working")

    }
```

This is the Cancel Button function

```
 func cancelButton() {

        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: view, animated: true)
         snapshot.progress?.pause()

    }
```

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

Comment: Where you have added `cancelButton` function?

Comment: @NiravD that's the problem i need to access         let hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)  to hide it. it is in viewdidload  but i can't have the cancelButton function outside viewdidload and access hud at the same time

Comment: could you post code from viewDidLoad?

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok please check the question again i have posted the code

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok i need the cancelButton function to have access to 2 things hud and snapshot.progress so i dont know where to put the cancel function

Comment: I am not sure - are you trying to just hide progress hud but tapping button, cancel download task, or both? could you show `cancelButton()` method?

Comment: @FyodorVolchyok i have added the cancel button function. The only problem i am having right now is when i put the cancel function outside viewdidload i dont have access to this snapshot.progress?.pause()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this -

Call below `showHUDWithCancel` from where you want to add hud with Cancel.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var hud = MBProgressHUD()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }
  func showHUDWithCancel(_ aMessage: String) {
    self.hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    self.hud.label.text = aMessage
    self.hud.detailsLabel.text = "Tap to cancel"
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cancelButton))
    self.hud.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func cancelButton() {
    self.hud.hide(animated: true)
    // do your other stuff here.
 }
}
```

Add this code within your `viewDidLoad` it will work.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appdelegate.orintation = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
    if book?.bookPath !=  book?.bookPath {
        print("HERE \(book?.bookPath)")
        loadReader(filePaht: (book?.bookPath)!)
    } else {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let strName = book?.id
        let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/"+strName!+".pdf"
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            loadReader(filePaht: filePath)
            return;
        }

        print("DOWNLOAD #1")

        let reference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: (self.book?.bookURL)!)
          downloadTask =  reference.data(withMaxSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {

            } else {

                if ((try! data?.write(to: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath, isDirectory: false))) != nil) {
                    self.db.upDate(id: (self.book?.id)!, bookPath: filePath)
                    self.loadReader(filePaht: filePath)
                }
            }
        }
        downloadTask.observe(.resume) { (snapshot) -> Void in
            // Download resumed, also fires when the download starts
        }
        downloadTask.observe(.pause) { (snapshot) -> Void in
            // Download paused
        }

       downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) -> Void in OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                self.hud.progressObject = snapshot.progress
                self.showHUDWithCancel("Downloading")
            }
          }
        }


        downloadTask.observe(.success) { (snapshot) -> Void in OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            // Download completed successfully

            print("Download Success")
                OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                 SwiftLoader.hide()
                }
            }
        }

        downloadTask.observe(.failure) { (snapshot) -> Void in OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            //Download failed

            print("Download failed")
               OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
            }
        }
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: This is tested code and it is working for me.. ok tell me it is not visible OR cancel is not working??

Comment: it is not visible

Comment: i managed to make it work but it got 2 problems the first one is cancel is not working and the second one i will attach a picture to show you and the code i used

Comment: you see in the 2 images above the one left get displayed then the on the right and so on. like it keeps flickering. and touch is working but not hiding it maybe because of that problem

Comment: call method in main thread.. if you are call it from closure .

Comment: please check the updated question. i called it from main thread but app is crashing. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: still doing same issue

Comment: put it into your dropbox and send me your project link.

Comment: when you download it let me know so i cancel the link

Comment: i moved  self.hud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)   to viewdidload and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Move definition of `downloadTask` outside of the `viewDidLoad` method scope into the class itself. This way you'll be able to access task directly, not via `snapshot` passed in observers, or `progress` attached to either downloadTask or progressHUD. Doing so you could access task from any method of your view controller including `cancelButton()`:

```
task.pause()
```

instead of

```
snapshot.progress?.pause()
```

Final code could look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var downloadTask: FIRStorageDownloadTask!

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        let reference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: (self.book?.bookURL)!)
        downloadTask = reference...

        ...

    }

}
```

Comment: if i move downloadTask outside viewDidload , i will have to move let reference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: (self.book?.bookURL)!)   as well and i coudlnt do that because of book.bookURL. so how could do that?

Comment: yes everything is working except that it is started flickering as showing in the 2 images above the first image will show then second and so on. i tried running it on the main thread but still

Answer (score 0):

**NOTICE: For those of you who use the latest version of MBProgressView, the button documentation has been changed:**

```
/**
 * A button that is placed below the labels. Visible only if a target / action is added and a title is assigned..
 */
```

So, the creation should look something like the following:

```
class Tools {

  static func popLoadingDialog(viewParent: UIView,
                                 label: String,
                                 cancelTarget: Any? = nil,
                                 cancelSelector: Selector? = nil) -> MBProgressHUD {

        let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: viewParent, animated: true)
        loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.indeterminate
        loadingNotification.label.text = label
        if(cancelSelector != nil) {
            loadingNotification.button.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
            loadingNotification.button.addTarget(cancelTarget, action: cancelSelector!, for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        return loadingNotification
    }
}
```

and call it:

```
loadingIndicator = Tools.createLoadingDialog(viewParent: view,
                                                      label: "Please wait...",
                                                      cancelTarget: self,
                                                      cancelSelector: #selector(onCancelClick))
loadingIndicator?.show(animated: true)

}

@objc func onCancelClick(){
        // do something when the user click on cancel...
}
```